# How to do same without Extension Method

Tags: c#, linq, console-application, extension-methods

I have a program that displays output in XML format on console windows, that runs perfectly fine without any error, but I am using the Extension Method to do the job. How to do this without using the extension method, I Have a hint that I just need to move one piece of line from extension class to program class but as a new programmer I failed and need your help.

Here is my **Main Class**

```
List<int> email = new List<int>() { 60, 50, 70, 30, 80, 65, 90, 75, 55 };

        var element = new XElement("Results",
            email.Batch(3)
                 .Select(batch =>
                     new XElement("Result",
                                  batch.Select(mark => new XElement("Mark", mark)),
                                  new XElement("Total", batch.Sum()))));
        Console.WriteLine(element);



        Console.ReadLine();
```

Here is my **Extension Method** class

```
 public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Batch<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items,
                                                  int maxItems)
    {
        return items.Select((item, inx) => new { item, inx })
                    .GroupBy(x => x.inx / maxItems)
                    .Select(g => g.Select(x => x.item));
    }
```

Comment: `this` is an hint about the difference between an extension method and a non-extension one

Comment: There's plenty of different ways to do things in code, so it's kind of hard to answer your question. Perhaps it would help if you explain why you're not comfortable with your current implementation.

Comment: What problems, specifically, did you have moving the code out of an extension method?

Comment: @Crono I am comfortable with my code but as a learner, I just want to implement code with a different technique, right now I just wanna do this without extension method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're asking how to move your extension code into your calling code. Here's how it would look like:

```cs
        List<int> email = new List<int>() { 60, 50, 70, 30, 80, 65, 90, 75, 55 };

        var element = new XElement("Results",
            email
                .Select((item, inx) => new { item, inx })
                .GroupBy(x => x.inx / 3)
                .Select(g => g.Select(x => x.item))                
                .Select(batch =>
                    new XElement("Result",
                        batch.Select(mark => new XElement("Mark", mark)),
                        new XElement("Total", batch.Sum())
                    )
                )
        );
        Console.WriteLine(element);
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: sorry for the late reply I had some family emergency, yeah that is exactly what I ask for, but that omits the Batch function, your code is working fine for me, but how do we use Batch function with that same piece of code

Comment: @Zong I'm afraid I don't quite follow. Your original question was how to do this *without* using your `Batch` extension method. Now you want to know how to do it *with* the extension method? 